# 304 error when refreshing the webpage using facil.io framework

Tags: c, sockets, http

I am new to facil.io framework. i create a simple server to load html page. when I open the local host in firefox it load  perfectly. If I refresh the  page it getting 304 message and showing the html text in the browser.

```
#include "http.h"
void on_request(http_s *request);
FIOBJ HTTP_HEADER_X_DATA;
int main(void) {
    HTTP_HEADER_X_DATA = fiobj_str_new("X-Data", 6);
    http_listen("3000", NULL, .on_request = on_request, .log = 1);
    fio_start(.threads = 1);
    fiobj_free(HTTP_HEADER_X_DATA);
}

void on_request(http_s *request) {
    char *filepath = "index.html";
    http_set_cookie(request, .name = "my_cookie", .name_len = 9, .value = "data",
            .value_len = 4);
    http_set_header(request, HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,
            http_mimetype_find("txt", 3));
    http_set_header(request, HTTP_HEADER_X_DATA, fiobj_str_new("my data", 7));
    if(http_sendfile2(request, filepath, strlen(filepath), NULL, 0)) {
        http_send_error(request, 404);
        FIO_LOG_WARNING("Can't read file %s", filepath);
    }  
}
```

**output :**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 26 Apr 2020 02:39:15 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3328b 252ms
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 26 Apr 2020 02:39:17 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -- 275ms
```

Comment: Is the browser displaying the right thing? If so, the 304 isn't a problem.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it showing the html as plain text not as normal view

Comment: @Myst can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

#### 304 Status Code

The [304 status code](https://httpstatuses.com/304) is not an error, as indicated [here](https://httpstatuses.com/304):

> A conditional GET or HEAD request has been received and would have resulted in a 200 OK response if it were not for the fact that the condition evaluated to false.

In this context it means that the Firefox browser sent an (`ETag` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) and basically said "send me the file only if the file was updated (it's ETag is different)".

Since the file wasn't updated, facil.io responded with an empty 304 response, indicating that the file wasn't updated.

At that point, Firefox displayed the file it previously cached instead of downloading the same data all over again.

#### Static file service - `http_sendfile2`

According to the [facil.io source code](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/c1306722fd84a23447671619fc76eb8a11a6cb39/lib/facil/http/http.c#L583-L605), the Mime-Type will be set automatically according to the filename, there's no need to set it manually.

In this context, you could skip the `http_mimetype_find` in your `on_request` callback, so it would might read:

```
void on_request(http_s *request) {
    char *filepath = "index.html";
    http_set_cookie(request, .name = "my_cookie", .name_len = 9, .value = "data",
            .value_len = 4); // do you use this cookie? ot the X-Data header?
    http_set_header(request, HTTP_HEADER_X_DATA, fiobj_str_new("my data", 7));
    if(http_sendfile2(request, filepath, strlen(filepath), NULL, 0)) {
        http_send_error(request, 404);
        FIO_LOG_WARNING("Can't read file %s", filepath);
    }  
}
```

Comment: yeah i use the cookie to the x-data header

Answer (score 0):

Use http_mimetype_find as html

```
  http_set_header(request, HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,
            http_mimetype_find("html", 4));
```

due to lack of information I did this mistake